# Getting HTML from Android Webview not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview

As per title, I am trying to get HTML of current webview content. This is how I do it:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

WVClient wvClient = new WVClient();
wvClient.setFirst(true); 
webView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
       progressBar.setProgress(progress); 
    }
});

webView.loadUrl("http://www.somthing.com");
```

MyJavaScriptInterface class:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void showHTML(String html) {
        Log.i("log","showHTML: "+html);
    }

}
```

WVClient Class:

```
public class WVClient extends WebViewClient {

private boolean first;

public WVClient() {
    super();
    setFirst(false);
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPageFinished(view, url);

   if(first){

       builder.append("javascript:__doPostBack('promotions_landing$A1','');");          
       builder.append("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");

       view.loadUrl(builder.toString());

       setFirst(false);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

public boolean isFirst() {
    return first;
}

public void setFirst(boolean first) {
    this.first = first;
}

}
```

Everything seems right, but it's not working. showHTML() in MyJavascriptInterface is not called. What have I missed?

Comment: Drop the `javascript:` scheme in the second `builder.append()` call. Also, it seems your code is mangled, as you're duplicating the showHTML call.

Comment: Yes i had that duplicated. Edited.

Comment: You should also remove the call `view.loadUrl(url);` from `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. The load is in progress, you don't need to start it again when you receive this callback.

Comment: Also, are there any messages in logcat? JavaScript errors and console messages will be printed there.

Comment: there were no errors and console messages printed

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Mistake is at MyJavaScriptInterface class, JavascriptInterface class implements Annotation thus annotation @JavascriptInterface has to be written in MyJavaScriptInterface class as below and there's no class constructor.

MyJavaScriptInterface class:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface{

   @JavascriptInterface
   public void showHTML(String html) {
       Log.i("log","showHTML: "+html);
   }
}
```

And webView's addJavascriptInterface change accordingly as below:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HtmlViewer");
```